# MySQL order by with count and group by issues

Tags: mysql

My Tables look like:

```
# Table user

user_id PK
...

# Table buy

buy_id PK
user_id FK
...

# Table offert

offert_id
user_id
...
```

Well i need to know the last 'buy' of 1 'user' and get the count of 'offert' this 'user' has, I tried something like:

```
select b.buy_id,count(distinct c.offert_id) as cv from user a
inner join buy b using(user_id) left join offert c using(user_id) where a.user_id=4
group by a.user_id order by b.buy_id desc
```

but it always returns the first 'buy' not the last, look like this order by doesn't make any effect

I know that i can do it with sub queries but i would like know if is there a way to do it whout use sub queries, maybe using max functions but idk how to do it.

thanks.

Comment: are you sure your buy_id is auto increment?

Comment: yes this column is auto increment

Comment: I edited my question i forget the 'where'.

Comment: maybe the user_id of newer orders is difference with your where condition

Comment: @mohammadfalahat the user_id has 4 buys i need to get the last with the count of offert this user has but it always return the first buy not the last, get it now?

Comment: the count come correct but the buy come the first not the last.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is simply not guaranteed to work.  One big reason is that the `group by` is processed before the `order by`.

Assuming that you mean the biggest `buy_id` for each user, you can do this as:

```
select u.user_id, u.last_buy_id, count(distinct o.offert_id)
from (select u.*,
             (select buy_id from buy b where u.user_id = u.user_id order by buy_id desc limit 1
             ) last_buy_id
      from user u
     ) left outer join
     offert o
     on o.user_id = u.user_id
group by u.user_id;
```

The first subquery uses a correlated subquery to get the last buy id for each user.  It then joins in `offert` and does the aggregation.  Note that this version includes the `user_id` in the aggregation.

Comment: i'm not fan of sub queries but in this case in think i'll need to do use it.

Comment: @user2379521 . . . My comment about that.  If you don't like correlated subqueries, update to a database that supports window functions.  That eliminates over half the need for such subqueries, in my opinion.